# How can i programmatically trigger a Lightbox window using Drupal

Tags: ajax, javascript

I'm creating a new module for a Drupal 7 site, and I was wondering if it is possible, using Drupal's AJAX functionality, to trigger a Lightbox window programmatically with PHP.

I have looked into the `ajax_command_invoke()` function, but unfortunately it doesn't seem to do what I need.

Edit: I would either like to run a custom function which would trigger the lightbox via  `$('#id').ceebox().trigger('click');` or using another way to programmatically achieve this. (This is an example I have taken off from a non-Drupal project.)

Comment: What would be the conditions that would open the lightbox?

Comment: To open the lightbox i would need to click on a button with an ajax callback, and if a condition within that callback is true, then the lightbox will be opened.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I achieved this by using `ajax_command_invoke(NULL, 'nameOfCustomFunction', array('select'));` with the following JavaScript code:

```
(function($) {
  $.fn.nameOfCustomFunction = function(data) {
    alert(data);
  };
});
```

Comment: "select" gets passed as the data var